# Modify RedirectUrl mid-stream (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, redirect

Can I modify the RedirectUrl in a page's load event? I can read it, but I'm not sure how to set/change it. This is for an ASP.NET site.

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: What do you mean? Are you attempting to redirect the user to a new page on Page Load?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft's built-in security--Membership, MembershipUser, Login control, etc. I have the user create an account, send them an e-mail with a GUID to activate their account. They click the link and activate their account. They get a message that says their account was activated successfully and to Login. They click Login and login, BUT ARE REDIRECTED BACK TO THE ACCOUNT ACTIVATION PAGE. On Login Page_Load, I'm trying to see where the redirect is pointing (checking query string), and if it's to the account activation page, I want to send them to Default.aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried setting the DestinationPageUrl of the login control, but the ReturnUrl had the final say.

Implementing the LoggedIn event handler of the login control and simply redirecting did the trick:

```
protected void userLogin_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Response.Redirect(url)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4.aspx) to redirect manually.

But somehow I think we don't have the entire story.